# Sending messages to an Iphone

Tags: python, iphone, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

So im trying to send a message my Iphone from my raspberry pi over bluetooth.
I have connected my phone to my Rpi succesfully and cant find any code to send messages with python to my Iphone.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to send message via bluetooth. You need to write an app for iPhone to communicate over bluetooth or choose another method of communication.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to Python and Flask Framework**:

Send message on sms from ios in swift -Twillo

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html
https://www.twilio.com/blog/tag/python